# How to control setuid, setgid, and sticky bits from chmod's numeric method?

Tags: permissions, chmod

I know how to set read/write/execute with three numbers from [the Arch wiki's file permissions page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php?title=File_permissions_and_attributes). I also know that `chmod 7777` will set the `setuid`, `setgid`, and `sticky` bits to `true`. But which number controls these bits? Is it the first or the last number? Which value is set to true when a `1`, `2`, or `4` is passed as this value?

Edit: I have added this information to the Arch wiki for future reference.

My question is much smaller in scope than the proposed duplicate.

Comment: That question has a much larger scope than this one, I do not think they are similar enough to be duplicates. Also, that question does not come up when searching for this post's title.

Comment: the idea behind a duplicate is that your question's wording helps lead people to the answers that already exist

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the `chmod` man page:

> A numeric mode is from one to four octal digits (0-7), derived by adding up the bits with values 4, 2, and 1.  Any omitted digits are assumed to  be  leading  zeros.   **The  first
>          digit  selects  the set user ID (4) and set group ID (2) and sticky (1) attributes.**  The second digit selects permissions for the user who owns the file: read (4), write (2), and
>          execute (1); the third selects permissions for other users in the file’s group, with the same values; and the fourth for other users not in the file’s group, with the  same  values.

Comment: Thank you! So, just to verify, `chmod 2777` would set everything except `setuid` and `sticky`?

Comment: That is correct!